# Scan the flag of a country in objective-c

Tags: ios, xcode, colors, flags, country

I need to be able to scan the flags of countries coming from my camera feed. I have found multiple samples of how to read the rgb values from a single pixel but so far I am unable to find a sample project or library where I am able to use the device's camera and scan if there are any flags or other colour patterns visible.

Several Libraries as Vuforia support object & image recognition but these are not based on colour, which is exactly what I need for this particular assignment.

Does anyone have any idea how this can be achieved or knows a library that can help me with this?

Kind Regards,
Philippe

Answer (score 0):

You can do custom training with the[Clarifai API](https://developer.clarifai.com/guide/). For example, you will be able to train different country flags, then use the trained model to predict any new images from your camera feed.